# Docker Mongodb replication on different hosts is not working

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to setup a mongodb replication in Docker containers running on different hosts. Please find the steps below:

1. In a VM1 running ubuntu 14.04, installed docker, then created container C1.
2. Similarly created C2 on VM2.
3. On C1 & C2, modified the /etc/mongodb.conf to set `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0`, `port=27017`, `replSet=rs0`, `fork=true`.
4. Now on both containers, started mongo using the command

   ```
   mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf --replSet=rs0 --smallfiles &
   ```

   (If I use `service mongod start` it says "unrecognized command".)
5. In C1, type mongo to start mongo session. `rs.initiate()` makes C1 as primary.
6. But when I try to do `rs.add("VM instance name of VM2")`, the VM2 is added to the replciation set. But in C2, the mongo doesnt change to secondary.

I have mapped the VM1 27017 port to 27017 port of C1. 27017 port of VM2 is mapped to 27017 of C2.

In `/etc/hosts` of VM1, C1, VM2, C2, the IP address of VM1, VM2 is added. Since the port 27017 of the container is already mapped to the VM, when we do `rs.add("VM2")`, the container `mongod` instance should have changed to secondary. But this doesn't happen.

Can you please help.

Regards, Sushma.

Comment: Please post the output of `rs.status()` of the primary. Use the edit function to add this information to your question. Furthermore, try to telnet to the port 27017 from C1 to C2 and vice versa. Please note that each replica set should consist of an odd number of members.